# Adding Checkmarx config to Jenkins build causes failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, checkmarx

My Jenkins build fails with this error:

> Error when executing failure post condition:
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: recipientListDefault for class: awsdMavenBuildPipeline
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
> at awsdMavenBuildPipeline.call(awsdMavenBuildPipeline.groovy:373)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy:761)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:395)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:393)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy:760)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2030)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2015)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2056)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy:750)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executePostBuild(ModelInterpreter.groovy:728)
> at ***cps.transform***(Native Method)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
> at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:402)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:314)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:278)
> at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
> at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
> at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

It only started since `cxName = 'API_my-app_name'` was added to `JenkinsfileAWSD`. The file now looks like this:

```
@Library('digitalSharedLibs') _
awsdMavenBuildPipeline {
    mavenVersion = 'Maven_3.6.3'
    javaVersion = 'java-8'
    appName = 'myappname'
    deployJob = 'digital-myapp-deploy-myapp'
    isAWSDApp = true // true if the application is deployed in AWS Direct, false otherwise
    targetDir = 'myappname/target'
    cxName = 'API_my-app_name'
}
```

I've been unable to find out anything about the `cxName` so am not sure if this was a typo on behalf of the developer who added it or if there is some other issue. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem before, because Jenkins installed the checkmark plug-in version is too high, can try to install a lower version of the Checkmark plug-in